# How do I `:reload` in `ghci`

Tags: haskell, plutus-starter, ghci

I copied the plutus-starter template: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter and created a file `BasicPlutusTx.hs` (and added it under `exposed-modules` in the `.cabal` file).

Then I started copying over all the code from the introductory tutorial: https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/tutorials/plutus-tx.html

As I work with the tutorial, I like being able to make changes to the code and then see how that affects things in `ghci`. I usually use `stack` and `hpack` and run `ghci` with `stack ghci`. When I do this, I can just type `:reload` in `ghci` and it recompiles any changes I've made. But that doesn't seem to work here. Even if I run `cabal build` in a separate tab, it doesn't. It seems like I have to quit `ghci`, run `cabal build`, and then re-run `ghci` and re-import everything again. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cabal repl` loads the necessary context or something so that `:reload` works as expected

Comment: Other answer was deleted because it was not an answer.  It was a suggestion if "something to try".  It should have been a comment.  This is also not an acceptable answer according to: [answer]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It answered the question. It probably would have been appropriate to suggest an improvement, rather than deleting it. This site will be most successful when people feel comfortable participating.